# Assign Tasks to multiple people with multiple completions

Tags: workflow, tasks

Sharepoint 2010.

Question 1:

I need to create a task that can be assigned to 1 or more people at the same time, but creates a separate tasks for each of the so that they would mark the task as complete for themselves.

The tasks might be "read this book", and once assigned, each assignee would have a task to called 'read this book'. 1 person may complete the task, but the other 2 will not.

I am open to ANY solution using sharepoint designer / or standard sharepoint.

I thought about using a workflow like 'Collect Feedback' - but I am unsure if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, "collect feedback" should work for your needs. I would do something like this:

- Create a new Tasks list, called "Reading List"
- Add the Collect Feedback workflow to the list
- Add the group or users you want to assign tasks to in the "reviewers" field

Configure the workflow like so:

- set it to assign tasks in parallel so all members get a task simultaneously
- set "expand groups" so if you add a group to reviewers, each group member gets a task
- set a due date and duration if you want

Now, when you add a new item (book) to your "reading list" list, it will assign a task to all the reviewers (readers.)

Done!

-Oisin

Comment: Thankyou. I will look to do so. Can the created tasks be on a separate list?

Comment: Yes, workflow tasks are always on a separate list that contains "Workflow tasks" there is one per site by defult, and it is configurable. OOTB, it just "works."

Comment: It doesn't have to be a tasks list either - it could be a custom list of your choice.

Comment: I am unable to start the same workflow for a new set of assignees. How would i do this?

Comment: You can only have one instance of a particular workflow association running per list item. If you are doing this in batches, you'd have to create a list item per batch of assignees. So if you've got three groups of people, that means three list items, and one workflow running per list item (three workflows)