# Multiple Assignees Sharepoint Task SP 2010

Tags: 2010, tasks

I would appreciate any help. I would like the task page to do the following. Imagine multiple individuals are tasked to complete a certain 1 hour training.

- I would like to be able to assign that task to them [under multiple assignee field]. Which I was already able to create, but my question is, how do I allow each assignee to mark ONLY themselves as complete, without marking the whole task complete?
- Also I would like the task to be marked as complete only when all assignees complete their task.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to make an individual line for each person?

This would make it easier to set up and manage.  You could add a new field which connects the individuals to make clear that they are a group doing the same training.  Either use a Training Date field with the same date and a field with the name of the training course.

Then you could set up a view using the 'Group By' function to group by date, training course or a combination of the two (You can use two 'group by' fields in a view, try experimenting with it, I think it could be a good solution for you).

You can set up an additional view to filter on [Me] which would allow users to see their own training items.  Add another view filtering on complete/incomplete.

Comment: The reason I am not doing individual lines is, sometimes I have 2 people to task, but sometimes I might have 20 people to task.

Comment: This existing Answer [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11265/assign-tasks-to-multiple-people-with-multiple-completions?rq=1] looks like it could be useful to you.  Otherwise you would probably need some custom Javascript coding which could be rather complicated.  Another option could be to create groups to assign tasks to, but you might have too many 'Group combinations' - it sounds like you're working with clusters of individuals from across the company rather than Departments.